# How is prāyaścitta different from daṇḍa? Are both complementary to each other?

Tags: dharma, sin, dharma-shastras, prayaschitta, punishment

How is prāyaścitta (atonement or expiation) different from daṇḍa (punishment sanctioned by the king)?

Is prāyaścitta a voluntary/self-imposed punishment for a sin that one commits?

Are both prāyaścitta and daṇḍa complementary to each other or are there sins where both apply?

Comment: It seems like prayaschitta is like a ‘sorry forgive me, I’ll henceforth put my mind into non-sinful activities ’. Prayaschitta is like some religious ceremony. You have prayaschitta like kricchra, atikricchra, Chandra something etc for these. Danda is as Ikshvaku said.

Answer (score 2):

> How is prāyaścitta different from daṇḍa? Are both complementary to each other?

**Prayaschitta and regal punishments (danda) both serve the same purpose: destroying the sin of the crime or sinful activity that was committed.**

According to Hinduism, the king's duty is to enforce dharma and prevent adharma (sins); there is no separation of church and state. So, a crime in a Vedic kingdom would be a sin. So all sins are crimes, and all crimes are sins. This is different from secular Western countries where the main duty of governments is to protect the rights of people and not interfere in religious practices.

Therefore, the punishment of the king serves as a type of prayaschitta:

> Manu 7.25 - Where dark-complexioned and red-eyed Punishment stalks about, **destroying sins**, there the people are not misled, provided that the Governor discerns rightly."
>
> Manu 11.99 & 11.100 - A Brāhmaṇa who has committed the theft of gold shall go to the King, and confessing his crime, shall say ‘sire, punish me.’, Taking up a club, the King himself shall strike him once. **The thief becomes purified by death**; but the Brāhmaṇa by penance alone.

So you can see from these verses that regal punishment serves as a prayaschitta. This is in accordance with the Vedic theory of governance; that the king should enforce dharma and prevent adharma.

> Are both prāyaścitta and daṇḍa complementary to each other or are there sins where both apply?

When to apply prayaschitta and when to apply danda is determined by circumstance, type of sin, caste, etc. Many of the prayaschittas cannot be done by shudras or women because the prayaschittas require recitation of mantras and performance of yajnas, which shudras cannot do. So for them, their purification would be done by regal punishment.

If the person doesn't do prayaschitta, then the king is obligated to punish:

> Manu [9.235](https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/manusmriti-with-the-commentary-of-medhatithi/d/doc201622.html) - The slayer of a Brāhmaṇa, the drinker of wine, the thief and the violator of the preceptor’s bed,—all these individually should be known as men who have committed heinous crimes.
>
> 9.236 - Even on all these four, **if they do not perform the expiatory penance, the king shall inflict corporal punishment along with fine**, in accordance with the law.

Medhatithi's commentary:

> For the crime of ‘Brāhmaṇa-slaying,’ ‘corporal punishment’ has been already laid down above,—in the rule that—‘the king shall put to death those who kill a woman, an infant or a Brāhmaṇa.’
>
> From what follows in the next verse it is clear that ‘corporal punishment’ here stands for branding.

So, if the sinner does not do prayaschitta, then he is to be branded as follows:

> 9.237 - For violating the preceptor’s bed the sign of the female organ shall be branded; for drinking wine that of the tavern; for theft that of the dog’s foot; and for killing a Brāhmaṇa that of a headless man.

And then they became homeless, outcasted, etc:

> 9.238 - Debarred from entertainments, debarred from sacrifices, debarred from education, excluded from all religious acts, these shall wander over the earth; abject and despised.
>
> 9.239 - Being branded, these shall be abandoned by Kinsmen and relations, deprived of all sympathy and greetings;—such is the teaching of manu.

However, the text states what happens if they do prayaschitta:

> 9.240 - But men of the senior castes [Dvijas], who perform the expiatory penances, as prescribed, shall not be branded on the forehead by the king; they shall be made to pay the highest amercement.
>
> 9.241 - For offences committed by the Brāhmaṇa the middle-most amercement shall be inflicted on him; or he shall be banished from the kingdom, along with his goods and chattels.

Medhatithi's commentary:

> **The condition of expiatory penances being performed does not apply to
> what is asserted here.**
>
> In the case of all these offences—of Brāhmaṇa-slaughter and the
> rest—the Brāhmaṇa shall be fined ‘the middle-most amercement’
>
> The qualification ‘unintentionally’ of the next verse has to be
> construed with this also.
>
> After he has paid the fine, he should be made to perform the expiatory
> penances.
>
> ‘Along with his goods and chattels.’—This is a special favour to be
> granted in the case of highly qualified Brāhmaṇas.
>
> In the case of the offence being unintentional, he may not be
> banished.

So for the mortal sins, even when the sinner performs the prayaschitta, he is still to be fined, banished, property taken, etc. but he should not be branded on the forehead and become homeless. So this is a case where prayaschitta and regal punishment are both inflicted; this is for the most heinous sins.

So, there are many things to consider like whether the sin was done intentionally or unintentionally, the caste of the sinner, the person who was the target of the crime, qualification of the sinner, etc.

Also, there is a difference between sins committed that other people know about and sins done in secret. The expiation for sins done in secret is much milder compared to the non-secret sins.

Comment: "[9.236](https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/manusmriti-with-the-commentary-of-medhatithi/d/doc201623.html) - Even on all these four, if they do not perform the expiatory penance" - what is the expiatory rite for "slayer of a Brāhmaṇa, the drinker of wine, the thief and the violator of the preceptor’s bed..."?

Comment: BTW, can you undelete & reopen [this](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/35917) question? Some users are trying to close/delete valid questions.

Comment: @sv, those expiations are already mentioned in the link i gave earlier.. posting it again here in case you were unable to see/read/understand it before - https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/the-garuda-purana-dutt/d/doc122585.html , they are also listed in here -https://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/manu/manu11.htm , from 100 onwards

Comment: @sv. The mahapatakas (most heinous sins) are: Killing a Brahmana, Brahmanas drinking liquor, stealing temple gold or Brahmana's gold, and having sex with your guru's wife. There are also other sins listed that are equivalent to these sins, like eating forbidden food is equivalent to drinking liquor, etc. The prayaschittas for these vary depending on circumstance but generally they are all suicide prayaschittas.

Comment: @sv. And yeah I voted to undelete that question. It is a very good question, though worded very poorly.

Comment: I don't understand how can there be an additional punishment by king if the prāyaścitta itself involves death. So for minor sins, prāyaścitta is voluntary and the king is not involved?

Comment: @sv. If someone does the mortal sin unintentionally, then in that case, the prayaschitta does not involve death. Or, if someone killed an evil Brahmana intentionally, then in that case the prayaschitta is less severe. In those cases, they would do the non-suicide prayaschitta and then the king would punish. And I don't think the king is obligated to involve himself in minor sins.

Comment: @sv. Like if a Brahmachari violates celibacy, then I don't think the king has to punish him for violating celibacy.

Comment: I like the first prayaschitta then danda part :). The prayaschittas are somewhat like pujas. They find mention in one of the Smritis ans the procedure is mentioned in Srauta Sutras

Comment: I disagree with your comment that danda is the only method of atonement for women & sudras. Raghunandana in his Sudrakrtyavicharanatattva of Smrtitattva & Kamalākara Bhaṭṭa in his Sudradharmatattva state that women & sudras can employ brahmin priests to pronounce Vedic mantras on their behalf & perform Vedic yajnas in their name. Certain prayaschittas like Chandrayana, Santapana, Krcchra don't even require homa & mantra as these are observed as restrictions on diet & behavior. Even if they are unable to perform expiatory rites, then the option of snana, dana & pilgrimage is always open to them

Comment: Fasting in Ekadasi & bathing during eclipse are renowned for cleansing all sorts of sins. Variations of Varunisnana are known to cleanse sins of even past births. Most importantly of all, a bath in the Ganga is enough to cleanse every sin. The tulasi is also renowned for it's sin-cleansing ability. Thousands of pilgrim sites are renowned for their sin-cleansing powers. Besides, Manu (as quoted by you) already states that those who have duly performed prayaschitta need not to be punished, so your opinion of punishment+prayaschitta is baseless. You seems to have ignored the 'or' in Manu 9.241.

Comment: If you say that prayaschitta overrules danda, then social order would collapse (a mentioned by Mitramisra in Viramitrodaya), then I would like to inform you that other smrtis have stated that such matters were to be decided by a Council composed of 12 brahmins who would conduct trial of the accused & then advise the king in formulating the final verdict. The notion of legal precedent is absent in the Hindu judicial process, instead cases are dealt on a case-by-case method. You have interpreted the scriptures in excessively harsh tones.

Comment: @AnubrataBit Ah yes, you are right. And for dvija women who have sinned, their husbands can also do the prayaschitta rituals if they require mantras. "Kamalākara Bhaṭṭa in his Sudradharmatattva" - Can you tell me who is he?

Comment: @AnubrataBit "those who have duly performed prayaschitta need not to be punished" - I agree with this. I don't think I said anywhere that you need to do both.

Comment: @Ikshvaku Kamalakara Bhatta was a renowned pandit from Varanasi. His grandfather Narayana Bhatta was instrumental in the reconsecration of Kashi Vishwanath temple during the reign of Akbar. Kamalakara Bhatta's seminal work is Nirṇayasindhu, which is considered as authoritive throughout India except in Bengal, Assam & Mithila. Kamalakara Bhatta's cousin Nilakantha Bhatta had composed a nibandha called Bhagavantabhaskara, which is respected as authority by Gujarati, Marathi & Konkani Hindus. Kamalakara Bhatta's nephew Vishweswara Bhatta had crowned Chhtrapati Shivaji.

Comment: Read History of Dharmashastra by Bharataratna M.M Panduranga Vaman Kane Volume I Part II to know in detail about Kamalakara Bhatta.

Answer (score 0):

In modern terms, what is the difference between pleading guilty and not-guilty for a crime that you actually committed (and gets proven later)?

Punishment is reduced if you repent.
Danda is reduced if you do Prayaschitta.

There are 4 stages of prayaschitta:

Realize = Gnana (understand the mistake)
Repent = Anutapa (mental regret)
Resolve = Sankalpa (shall not repeat)
Atone = Prayaschitta (physical self punishment)

The higher stage you reach, the lesser punishment you receive.

If you sincerely repent commensurate with the crime committed, punishment can even be nullified. But you have to follow scripture. You can't just lie on a hot stone, and claim to have repented for stealing. I mentioned that example, because some sects do that.
Some crimes are so heinous, that the prayaschitta prescribed for it seems worse than death. Fortunately or unfortunately, it's not. Something worse awaits later.

> are there sins where both apply?

Since most people can't/don't do the prayaschitta exactly as prescribed, the remainder of sentence is taken care of by Danda.
There is a ton of literature detailing exact methods of prayaschitta for each papa.

e.g. https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/the-garuda-purana-dutt/d/doc122585.html

Comment: Lot of speculation/commentary in the answer. Reference does not support conclusions. "Danda is reduced if you do Prayaschitta" - where is this stated in the link?

Comment: @sv, "A non-repenting sinner, or the one not atoning for past iniquities with the performance of a proper expiatory rite, is sure to be doomed to the pangs of any of the different confines of hell"

Comment: Question is about punishments on earth sanctioned by king, not hell/afterlife. This doesn't answer the question at all.

Comment: @sv, they are the same. king is simply an agent of God, as is Yama. your punishment is complete if you either 1. repent/atone, or 2. be punished by king on earth, or 3. be punished by Yama in hell.

Comment: Can you specify the source for the definitions and classification provided in the answer? The link sounds a general reference.